# Jax-Rs: Mapping json input to a bean using BeanParam doesn't work

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm using the annotation @BeanParam on my Rest method to map the JSON input to my bean. The problem is that @BeanParam isn't mapping the input.

This is the method:

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String test(@Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse, @BeanParam MyBean mb)
```

MyBean.java:

```
public class MyBean{

@QueryParam("a")
private String a;

public MyBean(@QueryParam("a") String s) {
    this.a= s;
}

public String getA() {
    return a;
}

public void setA(String a) {
    this.a= a;
}

}
```

My pom.xml is:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <javax-servlet.version>4.0.1</javax-servlet.version>
    <jackson.version>2.9.7</jackson.version>
    <version.jersey>2.25</version.jersey>
</properties>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax-servlet.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I'm using Java 8, Jersey 2.25 and WildFly 14.
The Rest service class extends org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.

I'm not understanding why isn't working.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. What does the JSON have to do with the @BeanParam? What _exactly_ are you trying to make work?

Comment: What I want is to receive a JSON like {"prop1"="A", "prop2"="B"} and mapping it to a bean X with prop1 and prop2 as inner varables passing only X as method param.